# Not sure if I am doing this correctly

Tags: r, statistics

I am working on propensity score weighting and I want to use logistic regression to estimate the ATEs.

There are 3 covariates (Institution.Cluster, Education and SuicidalAttempt_yn) and 2 variables(clozapine.or.not and death_yn).

The data of Institution Cluster are string, e.g., AKE ABE AIE AOE

For Education: Primary, Secondary, tertiary

Suicidal Attempt: 1 or 0

Clozapine or not: 1 or 0

death_yn: 1 or 0

Since I want to compare the mortality of both clozapine and control group. I am not sure if I should do the analysis separately or combined.

However, I still try to combine both clozapine and control group together.

Therefore, I used group_by(clozapine.or.not) to generate the result.

```
models <-  df_all %>% 
  group_by(clozapine.or.not) %>% 
  do(model = glm(death_yn ~
                   Education +
                   Institution.Cluster +
                   SuicidalAttempt_yn ,
                 data = df_all ,
                 family = binomial(logit)))
models$model
```

The output:

```
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = death_yn ~ Education + Institution.Cluster + SuicidalAttempt_yn, 
    family = binomial(logit), data = df_all)

Coefficients:
               (Intercept)  EducationLess than Primary            EducationPrimary          EducationSecondary  EducationTertiary or above  EducationTertiary or above  
                  -0.99253                    -0.02816                    -0.40882                    -1.21096                    -1.61048                   -11.58372  
          EducationUnknown      Institution.ClusterHKW       Institution.ClusterKC       Institution.ClusterKE       Institution.ClusterKW      Institution.ClusterNTE  
                  -0.52788                     0.07147                     0.11661                    -0.18822                     0.41416                    -0.11384  
    Institution.ClusterNTW  Institution.ClusterUnknown         SuicidalAttempt_yn1  
                   0.06603                    -1.78597                     0.14611  

Degrees of Freedom: 6220 Total (i.e. Null);  6206 Residual
  (83 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      5227 
Residual Deviance: 5031     AIC: 5061

[[2]]

Call:  glm(formula = death_yn ~ Education + Institution.Cluster + SuicidalAttempt_yn, 
    family = binomial(logit), data = df_all)

Coefficients:
               (Intercept)  EducationLess than Primary            EducationPrimary          EducationSecondary  EducationTertiary or above  EducationTertiary or above  
                  -0.99253                    -0.02816                    -0.40882                    -1.21096                    -1.61048                   -11.58372  
          EducationUnknown      Institution.ClusterHKW       Institution.ClusterKC       Institution.ClusterKE       Institution.ClusterKW      Institution.ClusterNTE  
                  -0.52788                     0.07147                     0.11661                    -0.18822                     0.41416                    -0.11384  
    Institution.ClusterNTW  Institution.ClusterUnknown         SuicidalAttempt_yn1  
                   0.06603                    -1.78597                     0.14611  

Degrees of Freedom: 6220 Total (i.e. Null);  6206 Residual
  (83 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      5227 
Residual Deviance: 5031     AIC: 5061
```

Does it mean I have already distributed them into clozapine group and control group?

Comment: The coefficients are exactly the same, you are doing it wrong. You are fitting the model with exactly the same data. Instead of `group_by` use `group_split` and fit with those sub-df's.

Comment: Q: *"I am not sure if I should do the analysis separately or combined."*. A: Combined. But that is a question about statistics and therefore more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RuiBarradas  I have changed to `group_split` but the `do()` does not work. I am new to R, what can I do for it?

Comment: You could try `purrr::map`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas It said Error in `as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default` How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try `purrr::map(\(x) glm(your_formula, data = x, family = binomial(logit))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  I have tried this `models <-  df_all %>% 
  group_split(clozapine.or.not) %>% 
  purrr::map(\(X) glm(death_yn ~ Education +Institution.Cluster +SuicidalAttempt_yn , data = df_all , family = binomial(logit)))` but there is still error

Comment: No, read my 1st and previous comments. If in the function you use `df_all` you get the *same model*  all the time. Use `X`. As for the error, it's not possible to say why it is happening without data.